# Custom changes does not apply on magento 2.2

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, custom

I reinstalled magento on localhost with the old database. 
Even though all extensions work as they should my changes on the custom theme under //Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml do not apply. All css changes work just fine.

Any hints?

I am new to magento, sorry for any missleadings if there are.

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I actually did it, and still no use!

Comment: Instead of  reinstalling with old database . could you please install with new database and then upgrade and deploy all custom module and theme

Comment: I wanted that to be my last resort! But i will do it and let you know if something comes up!

Comment: Did you applied your theme from the content > Design Configuration ?

Comment: The installation with a new database that @PramodKharade suggested worked fine! But still i am not happy of getting stated from the beggining! Anyways thanks ^_^